# C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, operadores

Olá, sou bem iniciante em Visual Studio.Instalei recentemente e estou tentando programas em c++ começando com programas simples porém um mesmo programa que rodou perfeitamente no Geany aparece com vários erros no VS2015.

Exemplo ( peguei um código qualquer na internet)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int custo;
cin >> custo;
if (custo <= 20000)
    cout << (custo * 1.05);
if (custo > 20000 and custo <= 40000)
    cout << (custo * 1.1) * 1.3;
if (custo > 40000)
    cout << (custo * 1.15) * 1.45;
return 0;
```

O mesmo, rodou perfeitamente no Geany no windows porém no VS apresentou o seguinte erro.

> 1>------ Compilação iniciada: Projeto: ConsoleApplication4,
>   Configuração: Debug Win32 ------ 1>Origem1.cpp
>   1>c:\users\tales\documents\visual studio
>   2017\projects\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\origem1.cpp(10):
>   error C2146: erro de sintaxe: ')' ausente antes do identificador 'and'
>   1>c:\users\tales\documents\visual studio
>   2017\projects\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\origem1.cpp(10):
>   error C2065: 'and': identificador não declarado
>   1>c:\users\tales\documents\visual studio
>   2017\projects\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\origem1.cpp(10):
>   error C2146: erro de sintaxe: ';' ausente antes do identificador
>   'custo' 1>c:\users\tales\documents\visual studio
>   2017\projects\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\origem1.cpp(10):
>   error C2059: erro de sintaxe: ')' 1>c:\users\tales\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2017\projects\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\origem1.cpp(11):
>   error C2146: erro de sintaxe: ';' ausente antes do identificador
>   'cout' 1>c:\users\tales\documents\visual studio
>   2017\projects\consoleapplication4\consoleapplication4\origem1.cpp(10):
>   warning C4552: '<=': operador não tem efeito; esperado operador com
>   efeito colateral 1>Projeto de compilação pronto
>   "ConsoleApplication4.vcxproj" -- FALHA.
>   ========== Compilar: 0 com êxito, 1 com falha, 0 atualizados, 0 ignorados >==========

Consegui tirar alguns erros do código mas um ainda permaneceu.

> error C3861: 'and': identificador não encontrado

tentei usar && e mesmo assim não funcionou. Alguem pode me ajudar? Muitos projetos que rodaram perfeitamente em outras IDEs não funcionou no VS.

Answer (score 1):

Precisa incluir o header "iso646.h":

```
#include <iso646.h>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6s3h5a7.aspx

Answer (score -1):

tente substituir o operador `and` por `&&`. Exemplo:

```
if (custo > 20000 && custo <= 40000) {
   ....
}
```